# Run-time error in .split("|")

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, runtime-error

I'm using that method in that line:

```
f.getCmbAttori().getSelectedItem().toString().split("|")
```

with an input like "13|Il Signore degli Anelli" and insted of return:

```
f.getCmbAttori().getSelectedItem().toString().split("|")[0] = "13"
f.getCmbAttori().getSelectedItem().toString().split("|")[1] = "Il Signore degli Anelli"
```

It returns an array where every character is alone, like this:

```
    f.getCmbAttori().getSelectedItem().toString().split("|")[0] = ""
    f.getCmbAttori().getSelectedItem().toString().split("|")[1] = "1"
    f.getCmbAttori().getSelectedItem().toString().split("|")[2] = "3"
    f.getCmbAttori().getSelectedItem().toString().split("|")[3] = "|"
    f.getCmbAttori().getSelectedItem().toString().split("|")[4] = "I"
    f.getCmbAttori().getSelectedItem().toString().split("|")[5] = "l"
[...]

    f.getCmbAttori().getSelectedItem().toString().split("|")[25] = "l"
    f.getCmbAttori().getSelectedItem().toString().split("|")[26] = "i"
```

How can be possible that? I'm wrinting this method in a wrong way? Here a piece of code where I use that:

```
PreparedStatement stmSql = null;
                 int risultato = 0;                  
                 stmSql = f.conn.prepareStatement("insert into recita (CodAttore, CodFilm) values (?, ?)");
                 stmSql.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(f.getCmbAttori().getSelectedItem().toString().split("|")[1]));
                 stmSql.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(f.getCmbFilmRecita().getSelectedItem().toString().split("|")[1]));
                 risultato = stmSql.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: `"|"` is a special regex character. If you really want to split on `"|"` use `.split("\\|");`

Answer (score 5):

The String.split function takes a regex, try using this:

```
split("\\|")
```

this will make it split on a literal |

Comment: Don't be pretty sure, **be sure**: [`String#split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)): *Parameters: regex - the delimiting regular expression*.

Comment: I also mean that is better to refer to the official documentation to strengthen the content of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Generally if you want to split by fixed string (instead of a regex) use `quote`:

```
.split(Pattern.quote("|"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `split("\\|");`

OR You can use

```
split(Pattern.quote("|"));
```

`java.lang.String.split` splits on regular expressions.

Twelve characters have special meanings in regular expressions: the backslash `\`, the caret `^`, the dollar sign `$`, the period or dot `.`, the vertical bar or pipe symbol `|`, the question mark `?`, the asterisk or star `*`, the plus sign `+`, the opening parenthesis `(`, the closing parenthesis `)`, the opening square bracket `[`, and the opening curly brace `{`.

These special characters are often called `"metacharacters"`.

For [More](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)